# Errors when deploying Jar files to weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

This is the error log resulting from the exception. I'm not sure what causing it to fail during the deployments

```
2016-05-23 10:19:57,656 INFO [com.sdars.util.EJBUtil]: {java.naming.provider.url=t3:/localhost:7001, java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory, weblogic.jndi.enableServerAffinity=true}
    2016-05-23 10:19:57,656 INFO [com.sdars.util.EJBUtil]: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: t3:/localhost:7001 [Root exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: t3:/localhost:7001]
                    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:36)
                    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:808)
                    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:365)
                    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:319)
                    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)
                    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
                    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)

                Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: t3:/localhost:7001
                    at weblogic.protocol.ServerURL.parseURL(ServerURL.java:486)
                    at weblogic.protocol.ServerURL.<init>(ServerURL.java:104)
                    at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.<init>(ServerURL.java:49)
                    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:335)
                    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the error is due to trivial typo in `java.naming.provider.url` property value. Missing a `/` in the url.

Change from : `t3:/localhost:7001`
to : `t3://localhost:7001`

You may look at an example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13717/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT369) from oracle's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Exception you are getting is 
Root exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: t3:/localhost:7001. Standard weblogic url is of following format.

```
t3://ip:port
```

Looks like you are missing / in your url configuration

`t3://localhost:7001`